Bluez - BLE trouble connecting to BT dual mode devices
I have two devices running Bluez in linux. I'm writing a C application using GDBus and bluez v5.54. The application is a sample app meant to demonstrate how to write code for bluetooth low energy.
I encountered a problem when one bluez device is running a discovery session it cannot find the other bluez device who is advertising. If I then set the "discoverable" flag in the adapter of the device advertising, then the scanning device will discover it. But by setting this discoverable flag, it also puts the bluetooth classic radio in pairing mode and it starts responding to paging request sent from the bluez device running the discovery session. The bluez method "StartDiscovery" performs bluetooth classic inquires and scanning on BLE adv channels at the same time. The bluez docs show a "transport" property in the adapter that should allow for selecting which BT devices i want to discover but this property is not present in bluetoothd for some reason. It will then discover the peripheral bluez device and present it on the dbus as only one object. This object then changes back and forth to represent the BLE and the classic device. This is in part due to the fact that when advertising with the "type" property set as peripheral, bluez requires me to use the public address to advertise, the same address used in BT BR/EDR.
Perhaps if I could have BLE and BR/EDR use different addresses, this issue could be avoidable.
Now if i call the connect method on that dbus object from the central, it will 95% of the time reject the connection due to an attempt to connect a BLE central to a classic device.
I have had very little success in getting a connection.
The same problem is observed in bluetoothctl.
Note that my wireshark ble sniffer (and nRF connect mobile app) will find the bluez advertisement without the "discoverable" adapter property set but not my other bluez device. I suspect this is due to some form of passive scanning the discovery method is using and/or the advertisement is using LE limited discovery vs LE general discovery.
I am concerned this issue will arise with other BLE peripherals/ advertisers (not bluez) when bluez tries to discover them but cannot.
Has anyone found a solution to this? Or encountered the same problem?
I tired  only calling the connect method when i find the name of the BLE peripheral but connect() still fails 95% of the time.
The newest version of bluez appears to have LEAdvertising monitor but upgrading is not an option doe to the linux kernel version I am using at this time. Newer bluez versions are incompatible.

I have discovered to get reliable connection it is best to put the controller of the "le" peripheral device into "le only" mode. This is done in the /etc/bluetooth/main.conf file by ensuring that it contains the following: ControllerMode = le

I had a similar problem. In my case, I suspect it had two causes: the server's advertising and the client's cache. Maybe your Linux client will not do this, but some clients seem to store information about addresses they have seen, and they assume that the identity will always be the same. So instead of reading the currently advertised info, a client uses the cached info, and can treat an LE device as the BR/EDR device that it saw earlier. My solution is to use a new address as you suggest, but it is not compatible with GDbus or bluez.
